# CAn not open port 1514 in ubuntu iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ossec

I am installing OSSEC and it says that i need to open port 1514 and 514 in firewall.

Now i have added the rule for port 1514 but i still can't get coonect if i use telney like

```
ossec-hids-2.5]# telnet 192.168.1.95 1514
Trying 192.168.1.95...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.95: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Now i have turned off the iptables but still i can connect. Does it mean that Telent can't be used for port checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get `Connection refused` it is likely that the firewall is opened, the problem would be that the service is not running on `192.168.1.95:1514`.

If the service is actually running, please post the output of

```
  iptables -L -n
```

`telnet` can be used for (TCP) port checking.

Comment: I have turned off the firewall and hosts.aloow is also all. Also even if the service is not running should't i still get connected.

Comment: No, if a service doesn't bind to the port 1514 server side, the OS will return an error that will make the client display *connection refused* - if you just want to test the connectivity to that port you shoul run a working service that binds to that port (or inetd.conf / xinet.d that will establish the connection then transfer to an application [eg telnetd]. The service configuration has to be changed a bit to accept connections on that port).